# How to combine two columns in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I don't know if the correct thing is to combine the columns but I have the following problem that I would like to solve with you and you can give me a better orientation and it is the following:

I have two excel sheets which I am using as a data source for a report in Power BI, one of these sheets has the following data:

**SHEET 1:**

[image]

And the other excel sheet with this data:

**SHEET 2:**

[image]

In the same report I want to represent the information of the two sheets, as you well know in Power BI each excel sheet represents it as a table, but when adding the filter of `Location` sheet 1 it does not bring me the values ​​of Area C, I understand that it's because I'm filtering by the column `Location` of sheet 1.

What I want to do is have a global column `Location` as a filter where the values ​​are found `Area A, Area B, Area C,` and when executing the filter they are dynamically applied to the data found in sheet 1 and sheet 2.

I don't see any point in having two `Location` filters with the only difference being that one has more values ​​than the other.

I don't know if the correct thing is to combine the two columns or make a many-to-many relationship, I hope you can guide me to make the best decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Location dimension table in Power Query that combines the values of Sheet1 and Sheet2. Assuming your existing tables are named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", this Power Query would build the dimension:

```
let
    Source = Sheet1,
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({Source, Sheet2}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Appended Query",{"Location "}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

[image]

**Update: (steps to create the query above)**

1. Right click your existing **Sheet1** query and select **Reference**. This will create a new query that references the final result of the Sheet1 query. If the Sheet1 query is modified, this new query will get those changes too.
2. Then click **Home > Append Queries**
3. In the dropdown, select your query for Sheet2 and click **OK**
4. Right click the **Location** column and select **Remove Other Columns**
5. Right click the **Location** column again and select **Remove Duplicates**
6. If your data has any blank values, you should also filter those out using the dropdown on the **Location** column.
7. You should also change the name of the query to **Locations**

Then create a relationship between Locations[Location] and Sheet1[Location], as well as between Locations[Location] and Sheet2[Location].

**Update: (Steps to create a relationship)**

1. From the Power BI screen (not Power Query!), select **Modeling > Manage relationships**
2. Click the **New...** button
3. In the top drop down, select the table for **Sheet1**
4. In the second drop down, select the table for **Locations**
5. You should see the **Location** column selected for each table. Also make sure the **Cardinality** is set to "Many to one", the **Cross filter direction** should be "Single" and the checkbox selected for **Make this relationship active**. Then click **OK**
   [image: Adding relationship]
   Then repeat the steps above for Sheet2 and Locations.

In your reports, use the Locations[Location] column, not Sheet1[Location] or Sheet2[Location].

Comment: Can you support me on how to create the dimension table recently I am exploring the Power Query tool

Comment: Added steps above.

Comment: Excellent answer, clear and concise